# Adding numbers to a csv file python

Tags: python, list, csv

Was wondering how I would add a number to an existing number in a csv
list? 
For instance,
If my csv list looked like:
hello,2, 11
goodbye, 5, 6
salutations, 7, 17
..................
 If my list looked like:
 [['hello','5','1'], ['goodbye', '12', '8'],
 ['salutations', '14,'9']................... ]

I have the basic outline for writing a file

```
with open("namesList.csv", "w") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(ranking)
```

Just can't seem to work out how to add the numbers
Many thanks

The end list would ideally look as follows:
hello, 7, 12
goodbye, 17, 14
salutations, 21, 26

Comment: Hi, it's very unclear what you're trying to achieve here. A good idea would be to give a bit more background about the scenario you're working on and the things you've tried besides writing the CSV file.

Comment: Hi, my apologies you're correct it probably isn't very clear !  I'm currently creating something that changes the third value in each of the lists [2] a set number of times.  When this loop is finished, these lists would be written to a csv file and the the list values would be reset and populated again by the loop, which when finished would in turn add the values to the csv file.  (By adding here I mean adding numbers so if  [2] in the csv file is 3 and 2 is getting added it will be 5)  Hopefully this is a little more clear !

Comment: Can you edit the question and add the code that modifies the lists? That would make this question more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
l=[['hello','5','1'], ['goodbye', '12', '8'], ['salutations', '14','9']]
y=[]

# Read the csv, match first element in csv with that in list
# Creates a new list y, with the updated values
# While updating the sum, had to convert to integer as the numbers were in string format
with open("namesList.csv", "r") as fr:
    reader = csv.reader(fr)
    for line in reader:
        for x in l:
            if line[0] == x[0]:
                y.append([ line[0], int(x[1])+int(line[1]), int(x[2])+int(line[2]) ])

# Writes the values in temporary list to the same csv file
with open("namesList.csv", "w") as f:   
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for i in y:
        writer.writerow(i)
```

Assumptions

- CSV has data in the specified format
- the required list is available and has data in the same format specified (as I've hard-coded the indices)

Comment: Hi there Van Peer, thanks for the quick reply!  Just given it a little test and it looks like this could be perfect, however it seems to be creating a blank row under each appended row in the csv, which plays around with the rest of my code a little !  Do you know how this could be done without the blank lines?  Also, this answer is very comprehensive thanks.

Comment: @abercrombiefan1 thanks! try changing this `with open("namesList.csv", "w") as f: ` line to `with open("namesList.csv", "w", newline='') as f:  `;

Comment: You, my friend.  Are a lifesaver!  Thanks alot !

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pandas library to write csv files in python

```
dataframe = Dataframe.from_records(your_list)
dataframe.to_csv('directory/yourfile.csv')
```

Comment: Hi there!  Thanks for answering, I have looked into Pandas, but was ideally looking for a way to this without using the library.